# How to replace ALL characters in a string with one character

Tags: python-3.x, replace

Does anyone know a method that allows you to replace all the characters in a word with a single character?

If not, can anyone suggest a way to basically print _ (underscore) the number of times which is the length of the string itself **without** using any loops or ifs in the code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
mystring = '_'*len(mystring)
```

Of course, I'm guessing at the name of your string variable and the character that you want to use.

Or, if you just want to print it out, you can:

```
print('_'*len(mystring))
```

Comment: Thank you!I totally forgot you can multiply strings

Answer (score 5):

```
import re

str = "abcdefghi"
print(re.sub('[a-z]','_',str))
```